# Method to get term URL in taxonomy in SharePoint TermStore using PnP JS library

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-store, term, pnpjs

Is there a method to get term URL in taxonomy in SharePoint TermStore using PnPJS library?

I am using this code to retreive term Name, Parent and ID:

```
export interface IPTerm {
parent?: string;
id: string;
name: string;
url: string;
}

export interface ITaxonomyPopulatorState {
  terms: IPTerm[];
}

public async getTermsetWithChildren(): Promise<IPTerm[]> {
    let tms: IPTerm[] = [];
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      const tbatch = taxonomy.createBatch();
      return taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_InjkMqAvKdUBok59vNz/Mg==").get().then((resp1: ITermStore) => {
        return resp1.getTermGroupById("7bdebaed-a684-4682-a5a6-6c1f1e976641").termSets.get().then((resp2: ITermSet[]) => {
          resp2.forEach((ele: ITermSet) => {
            ele.terms.select('Name', 'Id', 'Url').inBatch(tbatch).get().then((resp3: ITerm[]) => {
              resp3.forEach((t: ITerm) => {
                let ip1 = {
                  parent: ele['Name'],
                  name: t['Name'],
                  id: t['Id'].replace("/Guid(", "").replace(")/", ""),
                };
                tms.push(ip1);

              });
            });
          });
          tbatch.execute().then(_r => {
            resolve(tms);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

EDIT:

**Iterm** interface:

```
export interface ITerm extends IClientSvcQueryable {
    readonly labels: ILabels;
    readonly parent: ITerm;
    readonly pinSourceTermSet: ITermSet;
    readonly reusedTerms: ITerms;
    readonly sourceTerm: ITerm;
    readonly terms: ITerms;
    readonly termSet: ITermSet;
    readonly termSets: ITermSets;
    createLabel(name: string, lcid: number, isDefault?: boolean): Promise<ILabelData & ILabel>;
    deprecate(doDeprecate: boolean): Promise<void>;
    get(): Promise<(ITermData & ITerm)>;
    addTerm(name: string, lcid: number, isAvailableForTagging?: boolean, id?: string): Promise<ITerm & ITermData>;
    getDescription(lcid: number): Promise<string>;
    setDescription(description: string, lcid: number): Promise<void>;
    setLocalCustomProperty(name: string, value: string): Promise<void>;
    update(properties: {
        Name: string;
    }): Promise<ITermData & ITerm>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_TargetUrl

My debug screenshot:

[image]

Update:

The interface defined in pnpsp.

```
import { taxonomy, ITermStore, ITermSet, ITerms, ITermData, ITerm } from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";
```

Comment: Can you please show me your **Iterm** interface. I will update the post to show mine.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: I can retrieve _Simple link_ from **_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl**, but **_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl** returns nothing ; why? I would like to use **Friendy URL**

Comment: Check term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_FriendlyUrlSegment

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work :/ Is there any other manipulation to do in the term store management ?